# Integer solution of second degree equation

Tags: quadratics, integers

We all know that on $\mathbb{R}$ the solution of a second degree equation in the form $Ax^2 + Bx + C$ is given by:

\begin{equation}
\frac{-B \pm \sqrt{B^2 - 4AC}}{2A}
\end{equation}

Now, be $A, B, C \in \mathbb{Z}$. I want to find $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ so that

\begin{equation}
x = \min(\{y \in \mathbb{Z} / (A y^2 + By + C \leq 0)\})
\end{equation}

How can I get the solution to this equation by using only integer operators (so integer part for division) and having already the function $isqrt(x) = \min(\{y \in \mathbb{Z} / y^2 \leq x\})$?

I tried blindly using the formula above by substituting all the real operations with integer operations but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Sorry about that, @graydad, but I actually meant isqrt, integer square root: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_square_root

Comment: I can't understand:\begin{equation}
x = \min(\{y \in \mathbb{Z} / (A x^2 + Bx + C \leq 0)\})
\end{equation} What is the relationship between $y$ and $x$?

Comment: Sorry! My bad, I meant $y$. Will edit it immediately!

Comment: Oh I am sorry about that! Went into auto-edit mode :)

Comment: Does your $isqrt$ function give the positive square root or the negative? It's just that the way you have described it should make it always the negative...

Comment: Is there a difference? The way I stated it will always make it negative. In that case, $-isqrt$ will always be positive. You can also state it so that it will always be positive (making $y$ span on $\mathbb{N}$). Is there a simple solution to my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it this method should work fine as long as $A>0$.

The product, squaring and subtraction that go on inside the square root are all unaffected by the fact that  integer operations are used, because the variables are all integers to start with. The square root function will yield a value that has error $e<1$.

This negative square root is added to $-B$ with no increase of error.

The dividing should reduce the error to $\frac e {2A}$.

Comment: I thought about it again and actually it *should* work. Can't figure out why my code doesn't carry out the computation properly. Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us some output for sample values?